# Need help to understand QRegularExpression for my tasks

Tags: c++, regex, qt5

I have a QTextStream which contain:

```
Line1: 3 5 7 17 19 23 25 
Line2: 3 5 7 17 19 23 26 
Line3: 3 5 8 17 19 23 27 
Line4: 3 5 9 17 21 35 37 
Line5: 3 5 10 17 21 35 38 
Line6: 3 5 11 17 21 35 39 
Line7: 3 5 12 17 21 36 37 
Line8: 3 5 13 17 21 37 38 
Line9: 3 5 15 17 21 36 39 
Line10: 3 5 16 17 21 37 38
```

I need to create regular expression to select only lines which contain numbers 3, 17 and 37.
Line4, 7, 8 and 10.

How to setup pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are ordered, you might use [`\b3\b.*\b17\b.*\b37\b`](https://regex101.com/r/sBq0SS/1).

So in C++, with raw string `R"(\b3\b.*\b17\b.*\b37\b)"`.